# Add a new line between 2 files fetched by curl

Tags: linux, shell, curl, sed, posix

I have this command that fetches 2 files, performs some formatting and outputs the result.

```
curl https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v{4,6} |
    sed 's/^/set_real_ip_from /;s/$/\;/' \ > /home/user/output.txt
```

It works just fine, the question is how can I add a line break between file 1 and file 2 (preserving the changes to formatting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```
{
    curl -s https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v4
    printf '\n\n'
    curl -s https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v6
} | sed -r 's/^(.+)$/set_real_ip_from \1;/g' > /home/user/output.txt
```

Comment: Wow, I thought it would have been a one line trick and instead it's a bit complex.
I'll try this soon! ;)